# Установка драйвера windows 8.1

Tags: драйвер, windows-8

Не удааётся установить драйвер Intel Graphichs на Windows 8.1, ноутбук Gigabyte P56XT. Процессор KabyLake i7-770HQ

При установке появляется сообщение что система не удовлетворяет требованиям для установки драйвера. Это сообщение появляется для всех без исключения драйверов, от того, который находится на сайте производителя, до того, который рекомендует у себя на сайте поддержка intel.

Устройство определяется, как Intel HD Graphics 630 и вот дилемма.

Помимо установки из exe в папке драйвера можно установить драйвер через диспетчер устройств, указав путь к .inf файлу, который предлагает выбрать из списка устройств, для которых этот драйвер подходит.

Так вот, драйвер с сайта производителя и драйвер, рекомендованный интел не содержит в списке устройств Intel HD Graphics 630, а содержит аналогичные устройства от 515 до 535 версии.

При выборе любого из них установка не удаётся. После поиска на сайте Intel нашёл драйвер для Intel Graphics 630 HD, но он для win10 и при установке ругается, что не поддерживается данным типом процессора, хотя написано, что он для KabyLake.

В итоге нашёл программу DriverPack, которая правильно определила моё устройство и установила для него драйвер, и он даже работает, но, как я понимаю, это некая кастомная сборка, потому что время от времени изображение мерцает, что не критично, но сильно отравляет жизнь.

Хотелось бы поинтересоваться, несталкивался ли кто либо с такими проблемами, может есть какой то способ их решения.

Десятку ставить сильно не хочу, восьмерка и так большой компромис. Остался бы на 7ке, но она не uefi и есть проблемы с одновременной установкой её и ubuntu. Хотя убунту тоже можно поставить в legacy, но хотелось бы и рыбку съесть и.. Ну сами понимаете))) Помогите советом или делом, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Читайте внимательнее, третий абзац снизу :)

Comment: у меня просто в драйверпаками вообще не было проблем ... сорри